# WordPress + WPML Multilingual CMS Trying to switch language in header text

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have a WP site in dutch/english and would like to have the H1 in my Hero Image to change language according to the chosen language.

There might be a very simple solution to this but I can't find it.

hero image, h1 and button are all placed in header.php

concerns this site www.bedrijfsadres.amsterdam

Thanks in advance,

Ramonkey

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [gettext](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.gettext.php) functions:

```
<h1><?php _e('My text in default language', 'my_theme'); ?></h1>
```

This will echo the text in the current language. To translate it, go into WPML > Theme and plugins localization and click on the "Scan the theme for strings" button. Then in WPML > Strings Translations you'll find your string that you can translate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responds. I tried to find the Scan the Theme for strings option but can't find it. perhaps it's because I need to register WPML

Comment: It's on the bottom of the Theme and plugin page. See https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/theme-localization/